# "mount" does not recognize my drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am trying to mount a HDD but I'm having no luck. The disk is a 3000GB *Seagate SV35* that is exactly one year old. It is **a secondary drive** used only for data; the media center has an SSD for the OS partitions (Ubuntu 14.10).

The disk has been working very well in my media center until I powered that computer down normally. I powered up the computer a few hours later but it wouldn't start - I'm suspecting a [fault in the PSU](https://superuser.com/questions/932243/is-my-psu-defective) (also just 1 year old).

I want to access the disk so I have removed it from the media center and plugged it into a SATA dock that connects via USB to my desktop computer (Ubuntu 15.04). Oddly, **`Disks` won't properly recognize the HDD!** To the best of my memory, there is only a single 3TB Linux partition on that disk, so those 802GB are definitely wrong, and apparently it can't figure out the file system type or partitioning.

Given that the original host machine can't start at the moment, **how can I mount this disk on another computer?**

[image]

I've tried mounting the disk via the command line, using the `-t` switch to specify `ext2`,`ext4`,`ntfs`,`ntfs-3g`,`auto` but none of those work: `mount` answers that the format is invalid.

- dmesg output is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=X2HvJA6d).
- `sudo fidsk -l /dev/sdc` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 746,5 GiB, 801569724928 bytes, 1565565869 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT
```

- sudo file --special-files /dev/sdc output:

```
/dev/sdc: ; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), 
startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011
```

Comment: Connect the disk, do `dmesg -T` and see what the system says. Then `sudo fidsk -l /dev/`diskname will list all the partitions. `sudo file  --special-files /dev/`diskname will help, too.

Comment: @waltinator I updated my question with details for you. Now it's being reported as only 746GB but I am certain that I am looking at the right disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your USB to sata dock doesn't support drives > 2 TiB.  You will need to get another one or connect it via sata instead of usb.

Comment: **D'oh!** That sounds plausible, I didn't think of that. Thanks. I'll open my desktop computer and connect the disk properly, then see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Psusi! I've now installed the drive and [it is now recognized perfectly](http://i.imgur.com/1gZwgeG.png) and works as it should.